# Productive property of normality of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

I read in my text book that

> Normality property is not finitely productive.

(i.e if $(X_1, \mathcal T_1)$ , $(X_2, \mathcal T_2)$ be two Topological Spaces being normal,then their topological product may not be normal).

I don't know any counterexample in this context to show that this is the case.

Can anyone help me by giving an example to illustrate this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you ever heard about Sorgenfrey line/plane? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane

Comment: There is even a normal space $D$ such that $D\times [0,1]$ is not normal (with the usual topology on $[0,1].$)  Such $D$ is called a Dowker space, and was found only after decades of research. The Sorgenfrey plane is one of the simplest examples where $S$ is normal  and $S^2$ is not (as in the answer given).

Comment: Is $[0,1]$ normal ? I think normality is not hereditary..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Michael line is the following topology on $\mathbb{R}$: If $\mathcal{T}_e$ is the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is the subset of irrationals define a topology $\mathcal{T}_m = \mathcal{T}_e \cup \{A: A \subseteq \mathbb{P}\}$.

This is the smallest topology finer than the usual topology which makes $\mathbb{P}$ an open and discrete subspace.

Then $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_m)$ is normal but its product with $\mathbb{P}$ (in the subspace topology from the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$) is not normal. The irrationals are a metric space so certainly normal.

For full proofs see [this post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/) and there we also find a variant of this space which is Lindelöf, such that a product with a metric space is not normal.

There even is a so-called Dowker space $X$ (which is harder to describe) that is normal and such that $X \times [0,1]$ is not normal.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ denote the Sorgenfrey line; that is, $S=\mathbb{R}$ with the topology generated by the sets of the form $[a,b)$.
It's not too difficult to verify that $S$ is normal.

We argue that the product $S^2$ is not normal. Suppose by contradiction that it is normal. Since $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is a dense subset of $S^2$, two continuous functions $f,g:S^2\to\mathbb{R}$ that agree on $\mathbb{Q}^2$ must be equal.
If $\mathcal{F}:=\{f : S^2\to\mathbb{R} \mid f\ \text{is continuous}\}$, then this observation shows that
$$
|\mathcal{F}| = |\{f:\mathbb{Q}^2\to\mathbb{R} \mid f\ \text{is continuous}\}| \leq |\{f:\mathbb{Q}^2\to\mathbb{R}\}| = |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}^2}|=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0^2} = 2^{\aleph_0}.
$$
Consider the antidiagonal $D:=\{(x,-x) \mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. This is a closed discrete subset of $S^2$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. Hence any function $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $D$, and by the assumption that $S^2$ is normal, we deduce by Tietze's extension theorem that any such function has an extension to a continuous function from $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}$. This shows that
$$
|\mathcal{F}| \geq |\{f:D\to\mathbb{R}\}|=|\mathbb{R}^D| = (2^{\aleph_0})^{2^{\aleph_0}} = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}.
$$
Hence $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}\leq|\mathcal{F}|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, which is a contradiction because $2^{\aleph_0}<2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

A generalization of this idea is found in [Jones' Lemma](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/jones-lemma/).